# How to Close Preview When Exiting Denite?

Tags: vimrc, plugin-denite

Below is my configuration for `denite`. When I exit from a denite buffer without selecting a file or buffer via the `escape` key or `ctrl-o q`, denite displays the contents of the file or buffer that the prompt was on last.

How can I configure denite to not to open *any* file or buffer upon existing without selection?

```
" Denite:
nnoremap <leader>f :Denite -direction=dynamicbottom -auto-preview file_rec<CR>
nnoremap <leader>b :Denite -direction=dynamicbottom -auto-preview buffer<CR>

call denite#custom#var('file/rec', 'command', ['ag', '--follow', '-g', '--nogroup', '--nocolor', '-u', ''])
call denite#custom#var('grep', 'command', ['ag'])
call denite#custom#var('grep', 'default_opts', ['-i', '--vimgrep'])
call denite#custom#var('grep', 'recursive_opts', [])
call denite#custom#var('grep', 'pattern_opt', [])
call denite#custom#var('grep', 'separator', ['--'])
call denite#custom#var('grep', 'final_opts', [])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I had the same problem. There are two issues I encountered when I exited the denite buffer without selecting an entry: when using the `preview` action the preview window didn't close, and when using the `highlight` action the cursor stayed at the position that was being highlighted (instead of going back to where I was before opening the denite buffer.

I think what's going on is that denite runs some code when exiting the buffer to "clean up" these things like the preview window and when you simply close the window like any other window, this code isn't being executed.

I was able to solve that by defining the key mapping for quitting denite via the `denite#do_map` function.

```
autocmd FileType denite call s:denite_my_settings()
function! s:denite_my_settings() abort
    nnoremap <silent><buffer><expr> <ESC> denite#do_map('quit')
endfunction
```

This maps the `ESC` key to the `quit` action in the denite buffer. Then the two aforementioned issues were solved for me.